# The usage of adverbs anywhere and nowhere in negative sentence

Tags: adverbs, negation

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. Can you buy thіs magazіnе for mе? І sее іt nowhеrе.
2. Can you buy thіs magazіnе for mе? І can't sее іt anywhеrе.

The first one seems a bit odd to me. I've already seen this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61124/when-to-use-nowhere-and-when-not-anywhere, but it wasn't helpful

Comment: How is that question not helpful? user36815’s answer to that question answers your question exactly: both are correct and mean the same thing. What more is it that you’re not sure of?

Comment: The first is technically correct but, as you say, "odd".

Comment: Well, yes - both do mean the same thing, but the first example is not at all idiomatic. It's hard to define why you would always use 'not anywhere' in the context of an unsuccessful search. I suppose it implies that you have looked in all the places you can think of and the object wasn't in any of them.

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting! The concept of an unsuccessful search makes sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's clear to me that both are grammatically correct, but I've never heard the first one in real life. That was the source of my confusion and the aforementioned question didn't give the answer to that

Comment: Then your question is just not very clearly put: if it’s clear to you that both are grammatical, why do you start off by asking which is correct (making it seem like you believe one should be ungrammatical)? Are you really asking what the underlying syntactic-semantic criteria are for choosing between _nowhere_ and _[verb] not anywhere_ (and presumably also _no one/not anyone; nothing/not anything_, etc.)? That would be a very interesting question, but you’d need to flesh it out and ask the question more clearly to get good answers.

Comment: Oh, come on; it's obvious what the OP wants to know, i.e. whether the use of verbal negation or non-verbal negation affects the 'correctness' of the example. You're right @dodbrian, they are both grammatically correct, but the first one is not natural, not idiomatic. Nothing to get all bent out of shape over.

Comment: /I don't see it anywhere/ is the usual answer. That said, technically, one can say; I see it nowhere, it is grammatical but not usually used though I could sit here and imagine a context where it might be used. Also, one might say: It's not anywhere I've looked. [when looking for a lost object or finding something].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are technically correct, but the first is rarely used, if ever. Maybe someone might say "I can see it nowhere", but even that sounds odd. One way of saying with nowhere is *quite fine* however:

> "Can you buy thіs magazіnе for mе?" I'm sorry, but it is nowhеrе to be found."

Comment: it's not anywhere I've looked. :)

Answer (score 0):

'І sее іt nowhеrе' is so unlikely, you should discount it.

'І can't sее іt anywhеrе' is exactly what most of us would expect.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: "I see it nowhere" is used quite commonly.  It shouldn't be discounted.

Comment: I see what you mean and I think you're mistaken, but anyone's welcome to vote on that.

'It was nowhere to be seen' is fairly common and I don't think idiom gets much closer to 'I see it nowhere.'

Sorry I can't cite examples of non-use…